# How to use session in ExpressJS?

Tags: node.js, express

As i understood i can use sessions only inside the requests, something like:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    if (req.session.log_in)
        res.render('index.html', config);
    else
        res.render('authorization.html', config);
});
```

But if i have for example 20 or more routes so i need to write authorization check in each route? Is there something global with sessions like in `php` that i could check sessions before all routes and determinate and decide on follow-up actions?

Comment: You should read up on how to implement middleware for Express.

Comment: @robertklep can you provide some links on it as i using node for second day only….

Comment: AFAIK there isn't a definitive guide on how to write Express middleware, but you can start with [this guide](http://www.hacksparrow.com/how-to-write-midddleware-for-connect-express-js.html) (that talks about `connect`, but just replace references to it with `express` and it should work too). And [here](http://evanhahn.com/understanding-express-js/) is a more generic guide on how Express works, which also touches on the middleware subject.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Express allows a middle parameter of middleware called for that route. Use an authorization system like [Passport](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport) and call it like [this](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local/blob/master/examples/express3/app.js#L101):

```
app.get('/account', ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res){
  res.render('account', { user: req.user });
});
```

Comment: but still i need to add `ensureAuthenticated` to each route i use?

Comment: Or you can specify it for all routes, or for a subset of routes (and then add a `next()`).

Answer (score 0):

We can manage session in ExpressJS using express-session package. If you are running it in shared resource, you need to use Redis or something to keep it consistent.

Server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var session = require('express-session');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();

app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);

app.use(session({secret: 'ssshhhhh'}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

var sess;

app.get('/',function(req,res){
sess=req.session;
//Session set when user Request our app via URL
if(sess.email)
{
/*
* This line check Session existence.
* If it existed will do some action.
*/
res.redirect('/admin');
}
else{
res.render('index.html');
}
});

app.post('/login',function(req,res){
sess=req.session;
//In this we are assigning email to sess.email variable.
//email comes from HTML page.
sess.email=req.body.email;
res.end('done');
});

app.get('/admin',function(req,res){
sess=req.session;
if(sess.email)
{
res.write('
<h1>Hello '+sess.email+'</h1>
');
res.end('<a href="+">Logout</a>');
}
else
{
res.write('
<h1>Please login first.</h1>
');
res.end('<a href="+">Login</a>');
}

});

app.get('/logout',function(req,res){

req.session.destroy(function(err){
if(err){
console.log(err);
}
else
{
res.redirect('/');
}
});

});
app.listen(3000,function(){
console.log("App Started on PORT 3000");
});
```

Read complete tutorial here : http://codeforgeek.com/2014/09/manage-session-using-node-js-express-4/